# Adding an image via calculated column with SchemaXML not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add an image via calculated column in document library. It works perfectly well if i am doing it via UI as [explained here](http://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2014/06/11/adding-an-image-link-via-calculated-column-on-a-list-with-html-directory-list-solution/).

But when i am adding it via xml from visual studio, so i am getting following error:

> The element FormulaDisplayNames cannot contain child element img'
>   because the parent element's content model is text only.

Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{a8c7fe64-5791-416b-a837-26e93a3d056b}" Type="DateTime" Name="ArchivedDate" DisplayName="Archived Date"></Field>
  <Field ID="{b8581e64-01d1-4bef-9af9-06d190583664}" Type="Calculated" Name="Status" DisplayName="Status" ResultType="Number">
    <FormulaDisplayNames>
      =IF(ISBLANK([Archived Date]), 
          "<img src='/SiteAssets/red.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;'/>",
          ("<img src='/SiteAssets/green.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;'/>"))
    </FormulaDisplayNames>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="ArchivedDate" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

Can someone help me to find out what am i doing wrong? Or is it even possible to it via xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the Formula in:

```
<Formula>
  ="<img src='/SiteAssets/"&IF([Archived Date],"green","red")&".png' style='height:20px; width:20px;'/>"
</Formula>
```

*disclaimer: I shortened but did not test your formula*

I have looked into my files, never defined anything inside `FormulaDisplayNames`,
but I can't recall if you can omit

```
<FormulaDisplayNames></FormulaDisplayNames>
```

#### Update 1

I looked at my code, from some years back, in more detail;
seems you also have to encode in HTML entities

```
        _Formula = _Formula.replace(/</gi, '&lt;'); //      <
        _Formula = _Formula.replace(/>/gi, '&gt;'); //      >
        _Formula = _Formula.replace(/&/g, "&amp;"); //      &
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution that works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{a8c7fe64-5791-416b-a837-26e93a3d056b}" Type="DateTime" Name="ArchivedDate" DisplayName="Archived Date"></Field>
  <Field ID="{b8581e64-01d1-4bef-9af9-06d190583664}" Type="Calculated" Name="Status" DisplayName="Status" ResultType="Number">
    <Formula>
      =IF(ISBLANK([Archived Date]),
      "&lt;img src='/SiteAssets/red.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;' /&gt;",
      ("&lt;img src='/SiteAssets/green.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;' /&gt;"))
    </Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef DisplayName="Archived Date" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
</Elements>
```